# I18n::InvalidLocaleData: can not load translations with sidekiq and jruby

Tags: multithreading, jruby, sidekiq, rails-i18n, jrubyonrails

I have jruby-9.0.5.0 setup and i try to do some parallel processing using sidekiq. Everything works fine, except that if i use more than 12 sidekiq threads, i keep getting the following error message:

```
WARN: I18n::InvalidLocaleData: can not load translations from /Users/geroldboehler/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0/gems/rails-i18n-4.0.5/lib/rails_i18n/../../rails/locale/ne.yml: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
WARN: /Users/geroldboehler/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.5.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:184:in `load_yml'
```

The line that causes this is the following:

```
  I18n.t(".") unless I18n.backend.initialized?
  display_names = I18n.backend.send(:translations)[:de][:shoptwist][:display_names]
```

I need to load the values stored in the translation yml and the second line causes the exception to occur. I have absolutely no clue why this is happening, it probably has to do something with simultaneous access / some weird multithreading problem.

**Update**

I should mention that this worked when i was using MRI ruby, the problem started when i switched to jruby.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in an initializer and see if it solves the problem, it should eager load the translations before multiple threads start up:

```
I18n.t(".")
```

Comment: I did try that actually, but strangely I18n.backend.initialized? still returns false when i call I18n.t(".") in an initializer

Comment: It probably has to do with jruby because it worked when i was using MRI. And thanks for sidekiq btw ;-)

Comment: I managed to make it "work" now. I assume it has to do with the lazy loading of the I18n backend. To make it work i created a sidekiq worker that just does I18n.t(".") and after that, i can start as many workers as i like and the exception doesn't occur.